# Having problems reproducing Matlab results in Python for a coupled system of ODE's

Tags: python, matlab

I just started to use Python and have a bunch of code I want to transfer over from Matlab.  I started with a simple coupled diff eq and can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.  It appears that the second diff eq is almost giving me the appropriate results but the first equation is just remaining at its initial condition for the entire time span. The first image is the Python result and the second is the correct result from Matlab.

1) [image]
2) [image]

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from pylab import *

minfH_ab = lambda v: 1/(1 + exp((v+70)/6))
taumH_ab = lambda v: 272 + 1499/(1 + exp(-(v+42.2)/8.73))


Csn = 9    
I_ab_sn  = 0
gL_ab_sn = 0.045 
El_ab_sn = -50
gH_ab   = 0.054
Eh_ab   = -20

def dy_dt(y, t):
    dy1 = (1/Csn)*(I_ab_sn -((gH_ab*y[1]*(y[0]-Eh_ab))+(gL_ab_sn*(y[0]-El_ab_sn))))
    dy2 = (minfH_ab(y[0])-y[1])/taumH_ab(y[0])
    return [dy1, dy2]


t = linspace(0,1000,10000)
y_init = [-50, .0004]

sol = odeint(dy_dt, y_init, t)
S0 = sol[:, 0]
S1 = sol[:, 1]

figure()
plot(t, S0)
xlabel('time')
ylabel('voltage')
title('H & L Current')
```

Comment: 1. Throw a bunch of prints in.  2. Make sure you're not running into integer arithmetic issues (`50*6/5 == 60`; `50*(6/5) == 50`) -- try changing all integer constants into double ones (`50.0*(6.0/5.0) == 60.0`).

Comment: Thanks! I just took out (1/Csn) ,which was fine in Matlab, and simply divided dy1 by Csn and got the right result.  I have to watch out for these differences.

Answer (score 4):

Since this turned out to be the answer:

## Beware integer arithmetic.

If you're porting from a language that does not do this by default, you may be surprised when

```
x=50
y=6
z=5

x*y/z == 60
x*(y/z) == 50
x/y*z == 40
x*z/y == 41
```

And so on.  Try changing all constants to doubles (`5` -> `5.0`, etc.), and see if that helps.

EDIT: @BenDundee pointed out that python will be switching syntax to `/` meaning "real division", and integer division being specified with the `//` operator.  You can switch to that behaviour now, with the line `from __future__ import division`, which should also resolve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I just want to point out that this behavior was changed from Python2 to Python3. IF you want the Python3 behavior, you can add `from __future__ import division` to the top of your file.

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug 28 2012, 15:45:09) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple Clang 4.0 ((tags/Apple/clang-421.0.60))] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 1/3
0
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> 1/3
0.3333333333333333
>>>
```

Anyway, this isn't adding anything to @zebediah49's answer (i.e., (s)he should get the upvote), I just needed more space than was in the comments :)